# Html to run a system command

Tags: linux, php, html

I am trying to run this command to create a folder inside my raspberry pi but it isn't working. 
I am not good with PHP or HTML. I googled and i am unable to solve, so posting it here. 
If it is repeated and the solution exists. please do provide me the link. 
TIA
Code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['TestA']))
{
exec('sudo mkdir /www/test');
}
if (isset($_POST['TestB']))
{
shell_exec('sudo mkdir /www/test1');
}

?>

  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <table
 style="width: 75%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
 border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Test case 1</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Test case 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="TestA">test 2</button></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="TestB">test 2</button></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. This is a general programming question, nothing specific about the Raspberry Pi. I suggest you ask this question over at Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Read here http://php.net/mkdir

Comment: I sincerely hope the user your webserver is running as does not have permission to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you noticed you are try to run a command with `sudo`, that means the user **www-data** must to be included in the /etc/sudoers file.

I've tried your code, it works if i remove the 'sudo' and if i give permissions in the /www directory.

I think you need to configure the user in the sudoers file.

An example of my sudoers file:

```
#WWW-DATA
User_Alias WEBUSER = www-data
Cmnd_Alias CMDCOMMAND = /usr/sbin/asterisk, /sbin/iptables
WEBUSER ALL = NOPASSWD:CMDCOMMAND

#Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

You need to replace the CMDCOMMAND, with the commands your webserver will run as root. In this case `mkdir`.

Remember you need to go to **/etc/** directory and use `visudo -f sudoers` to edit the sudoers file correctly.

`sudoers` [Here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

P.S: If you want to test if your webserver could run a command, you can:

```
 su - www-data
```

After it will be a `sh` console.

You could run your command before adding in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directory with PHP without calling out to the shell. PHP has its own [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function.

Replace this line:

```
exec('sudo mkdir /www/test');
```

with this:

```
mkdir("/www/test1", 0700);
```

and do the same for the second mkdir command.

The first argument is the directory to create the second is the mode (permissions).

If you really want to create this directory in **/www** (see note about security below) you will need to edit the sudoers file for the www-data user as described in Ivan's answer or create the directory and change the owner. You can create the **/www** directory with the following:

```
sudo mkdir /www
```

and change the ownership with the following:

```
chown www-data:www-data /www
```

**Note:** Giving www-data sudo privileges creates a security hole. You should probably create the directories you need in the /var/www/html/ directory where permissions are not an issue and sudo is not required. If you do not want these directories accessible from the web, I would suggest creating them in /var/www and changing the owner.